# Shortcuts for # and $ not working on Turkish keyboard layout

Tags: macos, keyboard

My keyboard layout is "Turkish QWERTY PC" and the problem is that I cannot type the special symbols being typed by using <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> which are "#" and "$".

I opened the key viewer and typed <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>. It then says that I typed "#" but that's wrong.

Is there any solution to fix this?

I am using a Macbook Pro running Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Answer (score 1):

A [brief look around](https://superuser.com/questions/31153/keyboard-layout-creation-software) and it seems as though an third party application like [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=Ukelele) should help you map keys correctly for your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **right-side** <kbd>**⌥**</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause for a key or two not working is that they have been set as triggers for speech recognition or text to speech.  Double check system preferences/speech to make sure this is not the case with your machine.